# Show parsed JSON data in a list

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON file with data that is downloaded from my SQL server. I parse the data with the following code:

```
var dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);
var dataString = JSON.stringify(data)
var interestsVar = document.getElementById("interests").innerHTML
var result = dataParsed.filter(x => x.interests === interestsVar);
var resultString = JSON.stringify(result)
var matchesID = document.getElementById("matches")
var tagLi = matchesID.getElementsByTagName("li")
var li = "<li>" + resultString + "</li>";
if (document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML.includes(li)) {
  } else {
  document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML = document.getElementById("matches").innerHTML + li;
  document.getElementById("matchesCount").innerHTML = "You have " + tagLi.length + " matches."
  count()
}
```

That all works, I am able to get the data in the list that matches the search/interests box. I currently have it so it displays them in a list. I am wondering if there is a way to make them show up in a box and when they click a button they can either mark them as "ok" or "no", and basically shuffle through the options.

Comment: What's the purpose of `dataString`? You never use it.

Comment: It is used later in the function for testing purposes, just have not removed it yet.

Comment: Loop through all the elements of the array, creating a checkbox for each, with the interest in its value. Then use a JavaScript event listener on all of them that uses `event.currentTarget.value` to get the interest that they checked.